# Surveys showing GPS accuracy in different models of smartphones?

Tags: gps, coordinates, references, mobile, accuracy

Are there any surveys that give accuracy in meters for different smartphones (e.g,  iPhone 6: 8 meters, Samsung Galaxy S8: 7 meters) regardless of what the statistical method is being used?

Comment: GPS World magazine may have had some in the last year. Unfortunately, I recycled all but my last two issues. If you can access online or paper tech libraries, they will probably have copies.

Answer (score 1):

Tomaštík Jr. et al. (2017) investigated the [Horizontal accuracy and applicability of smartphone GNSS positioning in forests](https://academic.oup.com/forestry/article/90/2/187/2605849).

In Table 1, one can visualize which smartphones were used in the research:

- ZTE Blade (Android 2.3).
- LG G2 (Android 4.4 and 5.0).
- Sony M4 Aqua (Android 5.0).
- Other non smartphone devices.

It is not a extended list of smartphones (only 3), but I found it interesting because it gives an idea of what precision one might get under forest areas (leaf-on and leaf-off) in comparison to open areas; and what types of GIS tasks/operations one would expect to take advantage using smartphones (in context of forestry):

> ... The results indicate that ‘smart’ devices can be a low-cost alternative for forestry tasks with lower accuracy demands, e.g. under-canopy navigation, preliminary detection of points of interest, mapping of linear and polygonal objects of interest. Further benefits of smartphones, like the possibility of logging the data to central databases in real time, can make them competitive with other GNSS devices.

<sub>Reference:</sub>

<sub>Julián Tomaštík Jr., Julián Tomaštík Sr., Šimon Saloň, Rastislav Piroh; Horizontal accuracy and applicability of smartphone GNSS positioning in forests, Forestry: An International Journal of Forest Research, Volume 90, Issue 2, 1 April 2017, Pages 187–198, https://doi.org/10.1093/forestry/cpw031</sub>

Answer (score 1):

NTDP GPS Receiver Horizontal Accuracy Reports tests lots of devices under different forest canpoies, at https://www.fs.usda.gov/database/gps/mtdcrept/accuracy/index.htm

January 2023 data is there (at time of writing).

Also available as a downloadable spreadsheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**RTK (real-time kinematic) POSITIONING:** The availability of small RTK GNSS receivers, wireless Bluetooth connectivity, and the proliferation of publicly-available RTK bases provide an environment in which you can fully leverage the richness of centimetre-level, horizontal and vertical data.

**PRECISE POSITIONING SERVICE**

**INDOOR POSITIONING METHOD**

http://gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/

This article will help you in achieving 1-meter accuracy.

*In late 2016, Trimble introduced a software-defined GNSS receiver, Trimble Catalyst, that works with selected Android mobile handhelds, smartphones and tablets. The software-defined GNSS solution includes software running on the handheld, a small digital antenna and a subscription to the Catalyst service. With Catalyst, users can obtain positions in real time with accuracy ranging from meter-level down to centimetres.*

http://gpsworld.com/accuracy-in-the-palm-of-your-hand/

http://gpsworld.com/launchpad-spoofer-detection-for-surveyors/

Comment: I don't think Trimble Catalyst satisfies the original question, which was regarding accuracy of the Smartphones.   Other GNSS manufacturers also manufacture receivers which connect to Android phones - I know Trimble call Catalyst a "smart antenna" but it's really a receiver with all the RF stuff built in not an antenna.